# Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.10 - Login Loop (Xorg Crash)

Tags: xorg, amdgpu, 18.10

Just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10 this morning, and am unable to login using "Gnome Classic" or "Ubuntu", but I am able to login using "Ubuntu Wayland". Logging in with the first two options brings me back to the login prompt, with no errors or warnings. I believe the problem is that X won't start. Xorg.log is pasted below, along with my GPU hardware.

```
$ lshw -c video
   *-display UNCLAIMED       
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
      version: 80
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
      configuration: latency=0
```

.

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display|3D'
26:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390] (rev 80)
     Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. STRIX R9 390
     Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
26:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 290/290X / 390/390X]
```

I trimmed out the "modeset(0): Modeline resolution lines to make it fit below. Relevant portion is the last 25ish lines, anyway

```
[   426.510] (--) Log file renamed from "/home/andrew/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-3042.log" to "/home/andrew/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log"
[   426.511] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.1
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   426.511] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-135-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   426.511] Current Operating System: Linux Andrew-Desktop 4.18.13-041813-generic #201810100332 SMP Wed Oct 10 07:34:55 UTC 2018 x86_64
[   426.511] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.13-041813-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dpm=1 quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[   426.511] Build Date: 02 October 2018  06:40:03PM
[   426.511] xorg-server 2:1.20.1-3ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   426.511] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[   426.511]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   426.511] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   426.511] (==) Log file: "/home/andrew/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Oct 22 09:30:21 2018
[   426.511] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   426.511] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   426.512] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   426.512] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   426.512] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   426.512] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
Using a default monitor configuration.
[   426.512] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   426.512] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   426.512] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   426.512] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   426.512] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   426.512] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   426.512]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   426.512] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   426.512]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   426.512] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   426.512]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   426.512] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   426.512]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   426.512] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   426.512]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   426.512] (==) FontPath set to:
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
built-ins
[   426.512] (**) ModulePath set to "/opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/xorg/modules,/opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   426.512] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   426.512] (II) Loader magic: 0x55647430d020
[   426.512] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   426.512]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   426.512]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[   426.512]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   426.512]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   426.513] (++) using VT number 2

[   426.514] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_310
[   426.515] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   426.515] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 12 paused 0
[   426.518] (--) PCI:*(38@0:0:0) 1002:67b1:1043:04dd rev 128, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/8388608, 0xfe900000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000d000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   426.518] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   426.518] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   426.519] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.519]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   426.519]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   426.519] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card0
[   426.519]    loading driver: amdgpu
[   426.519] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card0
[   426.519]    loading driver: amdgpu
[   426.519] (==) Matched amdgpu as autoconfigured driver 0
[   426.519] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[   426.519] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[   426.519] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[   426.519] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[   426.519] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   426.519] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[   426.519] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[   426.519] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.519]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 18.0.99
[   426.519]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   426.519]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   426.519] (EE) amdgpu: module ABI major version (23) doesn't match the server's version (24)
[   426.519] (EE) Failed to load module "amdgpu" (module requirement mismatch, 0)
[   426.519] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[   426.519] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[   426.519] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.519]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 18.1.0
[   426.519]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   426.519]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   426.520] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   426.520] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   426.520] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.520]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.20.1
[   426.520]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   426.520]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   426.520] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   426.520] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   426.520] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.520]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.5.0
[   426.520]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   426.520]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   426.520] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   426.520] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   426.520] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.520]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 2.4.0
[   426.520]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   426.520]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   426.520] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card0
[   426.520]    loading driver: amdgpu
[   426.520] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card0
[   426.520]    loading driver: amdgpu
[   426.520] (==) Matched amdgpu as autoconfigured driver 0
[   426.520] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[   426.520] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[   426.520] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[   426.520] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[   426.520] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   426.520] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[   426.520] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[   426.520] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.520]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 18.0.99
[   426.520]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   426.520]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[   426.520] (EE) amdgpu: module ABI major version (23) doesn't match the server's version (24)
[   426.520] (EE) Failed to load module "amdgpu" (module requirement mismatch, 0)
[   426.520] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[   426.520] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[   426.520] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.520]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 18.1.0
[   426.520]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   426.520]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   426.520] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   426.520] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   426.520] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.520]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.20.1
[   426.520]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   426.520]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   426.520] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   426.520] (II) Unloading modesetting
[   426.520] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[   426.520] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   426.521] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   426.521] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.521]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.5.0
[   426.521]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   426.521]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   426.521] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   426.521] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   426.521] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[   426.521] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   426.521] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   426.521] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.521]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 2.4.0
[   426.521]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   426.521]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   426.521] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   426.521] (II) Unloading vesa
[   426.521] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[   426.521] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   426.521] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   426.521] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   426.521] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[   426.521] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[   426.521] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   426.521] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   426.521] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   426.521] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   426.521] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.521]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.0.2
[   426.521]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   426.521] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[   426.521] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[   426.521] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
"Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   426.521] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[   426.521] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[   426.521] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   426.521] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[   426.521] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[   426.521] (II) Loading /opt/amdgpu/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[   426.523] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.523]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[   426.523]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   426.523] (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
[   426.561] (II) glamor: EGL version 1.5 (DRI2):
[   426.563] (II) modeset(0): glamor initialized
[   426.563] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 has no monitor section
[   426.563] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-2 has no monitor section
[   426.564] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-3 has no monitor section
[   426.564] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 has no monitor section
[   426.564] (II) modeset(0): Output DVI-D-1 has no monitor section
[   426.564] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1
[   426.564] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-2
[   426.564] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-3
[   426.564] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: BNQ  Model: 78d6  Serial#: 21573
[   426.564] (II) modeset(0): Year: 2018  Week: 23
[   426.564] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.4
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Digital Display Input
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 10 bits per channel
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Digital interface is DisplayPort
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 60  vert.: 34
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Gamma: 2.20
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): DPMS capabilities: Off
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:2:2
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Preferred mode is native pixel format and refresh rate
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): redX: 0.660 redY: 0.332   greenX: 0.300 greenY: 0.629
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): blueX: 0.147 blueY: 0.052   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported established timings:
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 720x400@70Hz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 640x480@60Hz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 640x480@75Hz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 800x600@60Hz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 800x600@75Hz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 832x624@75Hz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): 1152x864@75Hz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported standard timings:
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): #0: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 60  vid: 49361
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): #1: hsize: 1680  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 179
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): #2: hsize: 1600  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 49321
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): #3: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): #4: hsize: 1280  vsize 800  refresh: 60  vid: 129
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): #5: hsize: 1280  vsize 720  refresh: 60  vid: 49281
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): clock: 241.5 MHz   Image Size:  597 x 336 mm
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 2560  h_sync: 2608  h_sync_end 2640 h_blank_end 2720 h_border: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 1440  v_sync: 1443  v_sync_end 1448 v_blanking: 1481 v_border: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Serial No: 46J01830019
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Ranges: V min: 50 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 89 kHz, PixClock max 270000 kHz
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Maximum pixel width: 1920
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported aspect ratios: 4:3 16:9* 16:10 5:4 15:9
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported blankings: standard reduced
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported scalings: hshrink hstretch vshrink vstretch
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Preferred refresh rate: 60
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Monitor name: BenQ GW2765
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): clock: 27.0 MHz   Image Size:  621 x 341 mm
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 720  h_sync: 736  h_sync_end 798 h_blank_end 858 h_border: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 480  v_sync: 489  v_sync_end 495 v_blanking: 525 v_border: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): clock: 74.2 MHz   Image Size:  621 x 341 mm
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1390  h_sync_end 1430 h_blank_end 1650 h_border: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 720  v_sync: 725  v_sync_end 730 v_blanking: 750 v_border: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): clock: 74.2 MHz   Image Size:  621 x 341 mm
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1720  h_sync_end 1760 h_blank_end 1980 h_border: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 720  v_sync: 725  v_sync_end 730 v_blanking: 750 v_border: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): clock: 27.0 MHz   Image Size:  621 x 341 mm
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 720  h_sync: 732  h_sync_end 796 h_blank_end 864 h_border: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 576  v_sync: 581  v_sync_end 586 v_blanking: 625 v_border: 0
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Number of EDID sections to follow: 1
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): EDID (in hex):
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   00ffffffffffff0009d1d67845540000
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   171c0104b53c22783a0cd5a9554ca125
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   0d5054a56b80d1c0b300a9c081808100
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   81c001010101565e00a0a0a029503020
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   350055502100001a000000ff0034364a
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   30313833303031390a20000000fd0032
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   4c1e591b041100f0f838f03c000000fc
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   0042656e51204757323736350a200130
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   020322714f901f051404130312021101
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   071615062309170783010000656e0c00
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   10008c0ad08a20e02d10103e96006d55
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   21000018011d007251d01e206e285500
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   6d552100001e011d00bc52d01e20b828
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   55406d552100001e8c0ad09020403120
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   0c4055006d5521000018000000000000
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0):   00000000000000000000000000000042
[   426.565] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output DP-3
    [   426.566] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output HDMI-1
[   426.566] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DVI-D-1
[   426.566] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
[   426.566] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-2 disconnected
[   426.566] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-3 connected
[   426.566] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 disconnected
[   426.566] (II) modeset(0): Output DVI-D-1 disconnected
[   426.566] (II) modeset(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[   426.566] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-3 using initial mode 2560x1440 +0+0
[   426.566] (==) modeset(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   426.566] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   426.566] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   426.566] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   426.566] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   426.566] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   426.566]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   426.566]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   426.566] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   426.566] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   426.566] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[   426.566] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[   426.566] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   426.566] (II) Unloading vesa
[   426.566] (EE) 
[   426.566] (EE) Backtrace:
[   426.567] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x139) [0x55647427f1f9]
[   426.567] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x50) [0x7f6dec651e1f]
[   426.567] (EE) 2: /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (gbm_bo_create+0x5f) [0x7f6de9c4e363]
[   426.567] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[   426.567] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f6de981f8e0]
[   426.567] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[   426.567] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f6de9823f40]
[   426.568] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[   426.568] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f6de981b940]
[   426.568] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (AddScreen+0xd7) [0x556474120b97]
[   426.568] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0x3bb) [0x55647416127b]
[   426.568] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x1cf) [0x55647412471f]
[   426.568] (EE) 9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xeb) [0x7f6dec47709b]
[   426.568] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x55647410e67a]
[   426.568] (EE) 
[   426.568] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[   426.568] (EE) Fatal server error:
[   426.568] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[   426.568] (EE) 
[   426.568] (EE) Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help. 
[   426.568] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/andrew/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   426.568] (EE) 
[   426.586] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Any luck on this? I am having the exact same issue...

Comment: Nope. My best guess is that the amdgpu drivers (as of 18.40) aren't compatible with Ubuntu 18.10 yet. I had to wipe and reload my system. Fortunately, it was a pretty fresh build so I didn't lose anything.

Also, the Mesa driver isnt compatible with the R9 390, so I can't use that. [link](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91880)